# Не запускается приложение на JAva

Tags: java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="quantity"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"
        android:text="Order"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

выходит сообщение об ошибке:

> Failed to compile values file.

[image: Failed to compile values file]

Comment: А ещё он пишет "checks logs for details". Вы это сделали?

Comment: Нет, подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: @ЯрославБуров ну можно посмотреть все логи, а не только ошибку. слева видно, что вы выбрали только один уровень ошибки

Comment: Как посмотреть все логи?

Answer (score -2):

Спасибо за то что подсказали мне посмотреть логи, я разобрался что это.
Ответ состоит в том что нужно было открыть в моем случае папку idx.xml и исправить там одну строчку . Там после этой строчки она почему то дублировалась как продолжение кода, я удалил и все заработало.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).